# How to set NA based on partial condition?

Tags: r

This is my sample dataset

```
df = structure(list(v1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), v2 = c("x a", "x a", "3", 
"x a"), v3 = c("x b", "x b", "x a", "x b"), v4 = c("x c", "x c", 
"x b", "x c"), v5 = c("1", "2", "x c", "4"), v6 = c(1, 2, 3, 
4)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I require to set all cells that do not contain the character `"x"` to `NA`

desired output

```
structure(list(v1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), v2 = c("x a", "x a", "NA", 
"x a"), v3 = c("x b", "x b", "x a", "x b"), v4 = c("x c", "x c", 
"x b", "x c"), v5 = c("NA", "NA", "x c", "NA"), v6 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` and turn the values that do not have `x` in them to `NA`.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) replace(x, !grepl('x', x), NA))
```

With `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(.fns = ~replace(.x, !grepl('x', .x), NA)))

#    v1 v2    v3    v4    v5       v6
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1    NA x a   x b   x c   NA       NA
#2    NA x a   x b   x c   NA       NA
#3    NA NA    x a   x b   x c      NA
#4    NA x a   x b   x c   NA       NA
```

Similar options with `str_detect` from `stringr` -

```
df %>%mutate(across(.fns = ~replace(.x, str_detect(.x, 'x', negate = TRUE), NA)))

df %>% mutate(across(.fns = ~replace(.x, !str_detect(.x, 'x'), NA)))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do

```
df[] <- replace(as.matrix(df), !grepl('x', as.matrix(df)), NA)
```